# Unable to get the value of textbox using ajax in a function in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a text box of weight where user will enter weight with button.
HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo "Weight:"; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class='help'><input type="text" value="0" id="ovrdWeight" name="ovrdWeight" size="12" />lb.&nbsp;Enter amount greater than zero to override package weight.</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<span id = "ewsLabel"><a id="generate_hxews_label2" class="button"><span><?php echo "Generate Parameters" ?></span></a></span>
```

Button click code:

```
$('#generate_hxews_label2').click(function() {
    $.post('index.php?route=sale/order/generateEWSParameters&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&Mailtype=' + $('#category_type').val()  + '&ClassMail=' + $('#classmail').val() + '&labelsize=' +  $('#hxews_labelimgsize').val()+ '&mailpieces_option=' +  $('#hxews_labelpieces').val() + '&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>' + '&ovrdWeight=' +  $('#ovrdWeight').val(),
    {
        token : '<?php echo $token; ?>',
        order_id : '<?php echo $order_id; ?>'
    },
```

so on..

Than in my function i am just printing this variable VIA get method but everytime i get 0 output.

```
$this->request->get['ovrdWeight'];
```

I have another dropdown list exactly here its output is accurate but not this textbox.

Comment: Use `$('#ovrdWeight').val()` not `$('#ovrdWeight').attr('value')`

Comment: i tried it but still 0 val

Comment: You tried it wrongly i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff i just edited my question thats how i have changed still same 0 value

Comment: If using POST method, why are you trying to get parameter value using `get[]` serverside? I'm not a PHP guru, but shouldn't it be `post[]`? BTW, how do you debug it? Does issue still persist client side or server side???  EDI>T: ok i see you pass varibale in url so get would work but this doesn't really make sense to me

Comment: I debug it with logs.. i tried it with post as well still it was same

Comment: `$('#generate_hxews_label2').click(function() {console.log($('#ovrdWeight').val());});` Expected value or still 0???

Comment: It shouldn't if you **set value** in input **before** clicking and use **unique IDs** on document context.

Comment: I dont know what the issue is iam stucked :(

Comment: I don't know either because you didn't provide any sample replicating issue, so...

Comment: what should i provide?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#generate_hxews_label2').click(function() {
      $.post(
      'index.php?route=sale/order/generateEWSParameters&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&Mailtype=' + $('#category_type').val()  + '&ClassMail=' + $('#classmail').val() + '&labelsize=' +  $('#hxews_labelimgsize').val()+ '&mailpieces_option=' +  $('#hxews_labelpieces').val() + '&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>' + '&ovrdWeight=' + $('#ovrdWeight').val(),
      {
      token : '<?php echo $token; ?>',
      order_id : '<?php echo $order_id; ?>'
      },
```

Comment: what is the value when you try that in console?

Comment: its value is 0 in console

Comment: is there any other  html object with this name?

Comment: Yes there was and that was the issue. can u please tell that whats the diff b/w attr.val and simple val()?

Comment: .val() works on all input type elements in a useful way, including <select>...even in the cases of <select multiple>, checkboxes, and radio buttons (in which .val() gets or sets an array of selected values not just a string).So basically they serve different purposes, even though .attr('value') behaves the same in some situations, like textboxes. The preferred method is .val() to get consistent behavior everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You define textbox value as 0.You need to remove value attribute from textbox.

```
<span class='help'><input type="text" value="0" id="ovrdWeight" name="ovrdWeight" size="12" />lb.&nbsp;Enter amount greater than zero to override package weight.</span>
```

Above element change with the following-

```
   <span class='help'><input type="text" id="ovrdWeight" name="ovrdWeight" size="12" />lb.&nbsp;Enter amount greater than zero to override package weight.</span>
```